# Rails 3 redirect on file upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, file-upload, controller

Afternoon all,

I have a controller that handles the creation of a new file upload (its a task so I can't use paperclip and its saved to the database so i know the downsides to all of these and can hear you grumbling lol) However when the validation for the file save fails ( i.e. trying to upload nothing) the redirect to the new upload form doesn't seem to do anything and tries to render the index page. I have tried loads of variations of the redirect using renders, redirect_to(:back) etc but none seem to actually do anything.

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

heres the code.

controller

```
def create
    beginning = Time.now
    return if params[:attachment].blank?

    @attachment = Attachment.new
    @attachment.uploaded_file = params[:attachment]
    @time = (Time.now - beginning)
    if @attachment.save
      flash[:success] = "File uploaded in #{@time} seconds"
      redirect_to @attachment
    else
      flash[:notice] = "something went wrong"
      redirect_to 'new
    end
 end
```

model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :anagrams, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :filename, :content_type, :data
  validates_presence_of :filename, :data, :content_type

  def uploaded_file=(incoming_file)
    self.filename = incoming_file.original_filename
    self.content_type = incoming_file.content_type
    self.data = incoming_file.read
  end

  def filename=(new_filename)
    write_attribute("filename", sanitize_filename(new_filename))
  end

  private

  def sanitize_filename(filename)
    just_filename = File.basename(filename)
    just_filename.gsub(/[^\w\.\-]/, '_')
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :attachments, only: [:create, :new]
  resources :anagrams, only: [:create, :new]


 root to: "attachments#new"
```

if anyone needs to see more code just shout, many thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the save is failing?

Comment: Hi Super, theres no record of it after jumping into the console after an attempted save with no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, the [:attachment].blank? was doing what i wanted the else statement to do, but i didn't think of putting the flash notice and render 'new' there. switched it around and works.

```
 def create
   beginning = Time.now
   if params[:attachment].blank?
     flash[:error] = "Please upload a file"
     render 'new'
   else
    @attachment = Attachment.new
    @attachment.uploaded_file = params[:attachment]
    @time = (Time.now - beginning)
    if @attachment.save
      flash[:success] = "File uploaded in #{@time} seconds"
      redirect_to @attachment
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirect_to the 'new', you should render the form again so that it can show the errors. For example:

```
if @attachment.save
  flash[:success] = "File uploaded in #{@time} seconds"
  redirect_to @attachment
else
  flash.now[:notice] = "something went wrong"
  render :action => 'new
end
```

If you really need to redirect, you should debug for the errors. You can dump the errors by this:

```
puts @attachment.errors.inspect
```

It looks dirty but we can quickly find the problem :D